# In PyCharm, suddenly some menu commands stopped working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In Pycharm Edu 2018.3 some menu commands and their keyboard shortcuts some days ago stopped working (menu commands are dimmed and keyboard shortucts do nothing).

E. g. while editing a Python file, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for commenting lines *does nothing*, and related command `Code | Comment with line comment`is dimmed. But in Python Console are both fully functional!

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> for running the code does nothing, too, but the green triangular arrow in the toolbar works.

I restarted Pycharm Edu many times without a success. Yesterday it suddenly worked, but after exiting and restarting Pycharm it stopped worked again.

What happens and how to fix it?

---

Note: In the same time, on the same computer, and with the same Python file in its editor window the Pycharm Professional 2018.1.5 works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Pycharm?

Comment: @DavidPostill, no for now, I'm worried about losing my settings, projects, and installed plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with missing association of `*.py` pattern with Python type, so PyCharm don't know that those are Python files, and consequently it don't know *how to comment* lines of such file, or *how to launch* it.

How to fix it:

```
File | Settings | Editor | File Types
```

and add `*.py` pattern into bottom part (click on +) after selecting "Python type" in the upper part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solution is simple:

Turn off **Vim Emulation** in the **Tools** menu

Edit: I had the same problem, and this solved. I suffered for 2 weeks on this thing and that irritated me but finally this solved.

it is working

Comment: To improve the answer, you should explain why this action solves the problem: for example, "I had the same problem, and this solved".

Comment: sure, thnks!!!!